# Timber hash link filter on menu links

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, twig, timber

I'm building a single page theme in WordPress with Timber but I'm a bit new to it so I'm a little lost on something that is probably pretty simple.  I just want to convert links to hash links with a filter but I can't even get the filter to run without errors (I just get a broken site when I add it like below).  Here is what my `functions.php` looks like in my theme (precis):

```
 class SIDSite extends TimberSite {

        function __construct() {
            add_theme_support( 'post-formats' );
            add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
            add_theme_support( 'menus' );
            add_filter( 'timber_context', array( $this, 'add_to_context' ) );
            add_filter( 'get_twig', array( $this, 'add_to_twig' ) );
            add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_post_types' ) );
            add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_taxonomies' ) );
            add_filter( 'hash_link', array( $this, 'hash_link' ) ); // Added this
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function hash_link ($string) { // function I added, is probably not 100% right but I can't even debug it
            if(substr($string, 0, 1) === '/') {
                $string = substr($string, 1);
            }

            return '#' . $string;
        }
}
```

And here is my `menu.twig` file:

```
{% if menu %}
    <ul>
    {% for item in menu %}
        <li class="{{item.classes | join(' ')}}">
            <a href="{{item.path | hash_link}}">{{item.title}}</a>
            {% include "menu.twig" with {'menu': item.get_children} %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

I feel like I need to extend something else, but adding my filter to the whole site should work in my mind.  What can I do to stop this from crashing my site?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, the issue is that Twig filters are totally separate from WP filters, so you need to register yr filter with Twig, not WordPress. Try this...

```
function add_to_twig( $twig ) {
    $twig->addFilter('hash_link', array( $this, 'hash_link' ));
    return $twig;
}

function hash_link( $string ) { /
    if(substr($string, 0, 1) === '/') {
        $string = substr($string, 1);
    }
    return '#' . $string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it pointed me in the right direction!  Just two things; I had to re-add the `add_to_twig` filter to my `__construct` function and I had to change my function a bit; making sure the filter is a `Twig_SimpleFilter` and checking URLs more thoroughly to make sure it can be used more generally but it works now.